# how may i set the verified links in the app when installed?

Tags: android, deep-linking

I am looking for ways to set the verified links in the app when it is first installed. Would it be any ways?

[android app setting - open by default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unJoA.png)

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it work, first you need to verify (connect) that you own the domain. See the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-android-applinks) on how you can do that. Otherwise, you will always see the popup dialog to select the app.